# Notify me popup disappears after few seconds in shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, shopify, liquid

I am trying to add notify me popup that appears within the product div when a customer clicks on soldout sizes. It works fine and appears when there is only one size variant and that is out of stock but popup box disappears after a few seconds when we have mix instock and soldout sizes. Here is the liquid file code:

```
{% if settings.enable_notify_form %}
<div id="nofify_sold-out" data-form-notify 
    {% if current_variant.available %}
        {% if product.available and variantCount > 0 %}style="display: none"{% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if variantCount > 0 and product.variants[0].title != 'Default Title' %}
        data-success="{{ 'products.notify_form.success_variant' | t }}"
    {% else %}
        data-success="{{ 'products.notify_form.success_product' | t }}"
    {% endif %}
        data-error="{{ 'products.notify_form.error' | t }}">
    
    <h4 class="title">{{ 'products.notify_form.title' | t }}</h4>
    {% form 'contact', id: 'sold-out_form' %}
        {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
        {% if variantCount > 0 and product.variants[0].title != 'Default Title' %}
            <div class="note form-success" style="display: none">
                {{ 'products.notify_form.success_variant' | t }}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="note form-success" style="display: none">
                {{ 'products.notify_form.success_product' | t }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                if ($.cookie('soldOut') == 'closed') {
                    // $('#sold-out_form .form-success').show();
                    var success = $('#nofify_sold-out').data('success');
                    $('#notify-soldout .modal-body').html(success);
                    $('#notify-soldout').modal();
                    var newURL = location.href.split("?")[0];
                    window.history.pushState('object', document.title, newURL);
                }
            });
        </script>
        {% endif %}
        <div id="notify-me-wrapper" class="clearfix form-content">
            <!-- <input type="hidden" class="form-input" name="contact[NOTIFY ME OUT OF STOCK]" /> -->
            <input type="hidden" class="form-input" name="contact[Product Title]" value="{{ product.title }}" />
            <input type="hidden" class="form-input" name="contact[Product Link]" value="{{ shop.url | append: current_variant.url }}" data-value-email />
            <input type="email" name="contact[email]" required id="contactFormEmail" placeholder="{{ 'products.notify_form.placeholder' | t }}" class="form-input input-field" value="{{customer.email}}">
            <input type="submit" class="button btn btn--secondary" id="soldOut-button" value="{{ 'products.notify_form.submit' | t }}">
        </div>
    {% endform %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

To display on the product page:

```
{% render 'nofify-sold-out', product: product, variantCount: variantCount, current_variant: current_variant %}
```

[image]